# Weird Issue on Macro For Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba

my code was working fine before my laptop crash(due to loads of data i presume) and now, when creating the pivot table it created error 1004 unable to get the pivottable property of the workbook class. The weird thing is, the code was working fine just this morning.

Kindly help to fix

```
Sub Pivot()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim ptField As PivotField
Dim ptRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long

' Set the worksheet where you want to create the pivot table
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name
ws.Cells.Clear
' Define the data range for the pivot table
Dim sheet_from As Worksheet
Set sheet_from = ActiveSheet
last_row = sheet_from.Range("A:Bj").End(xlUp).Row
Set ptRange = sheet_from.Range("A2:BJ" & last_row)

' Create a pivot table on a new sheet or existing sheet
Set pt = ws.Parent.PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=ws.Range("A1"), _
                                     TableName:="PivotTable4")

' Add fields to the pivot table
With pt
    ' Add fields to rows
    
    Set ptField = .PivotFields("Narrative1")
    ptField.Orientation = xlRowField
    
    ' Add fields to values
    Set ptField = .PivotFields("Column 1") ' Change "Amount" to your field name
    ptField.Orientation = xlDataField
    ptField.Function = xlSum ' You can change the function as needed (e.g., xlCount, xlAverage, etc.)
    
    
     With .DataPivotField
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
End With
sheet_from.Activate
End Sub

Sub Pivot2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim ptField As PivotField
Dim ptRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long

' Set the worksheet where you want to create the pivot table
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name
' Define the data range for the pivot table
Dim sheet_from As Worksheet
Set sheet_from = ActiveSheet
last_row = sheet_from.Range("A:Bj").End(xlUp).Row
Set ptRange = sheet_from.Range("A2:BJ" & last_row)

' Create a pivot table on a new sheet or existing sheet
Set pt = ws.Parent.PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=ws.Range("A90853"), _
                                     TableName:="PivotTable5")

' Add fields to the pivot table
With pt
    ' Add fields to rows
    
    Set ptField = .PivotFields("Narrative1")
    ptField.Orientation = xlRowField
    
    ' Add fields to values
    Set ptField = .PivotFields("Column1") ' Change "Amount" to your field name
    ptField.Orientation = xlDataField
    ptField.Function = xlSum ' You can change the function as needed (e.g., xlCount, xlAverage, etc.)
    
    
     With .DataPivotField
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
End With
sheet_from.Activate
End Sub
```

Issue is on this

```
`Set pt = ws.Parent.PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=ws.Range("A90853"), _
                                         TableName:="PivotTable5")
```

I want it to create a new pivot table with the specified range, but alas errors keep on arise. Please help.

Comment: Shouldn't that be ws.PivotTableWizard instead of ws.Parent.PivotTableWizard ?

Comment: aight! Trying it right now